# Magento : One product, two categories, two prices

Tags: magento, categories, product

Using magento, I need some help to display two different prices for one item displayed in two different categories :
The product is diplayed : 
- in category A with let's say a price of 100$
- in another category with a price of 95$

Question : How can I do that ?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Set the product up twice... It wont work the way you want it to i.e. Via Category, unless you use store views, and override the price per each store view. What exactly is the purpose of this?

If Retail and Trade prices, do it as customer group prices, or use different store views to handle this. Your proposed method does not take into account search results or users landing on the product page without browsing through a category system (i.e. Google search link). If you insist on having same product with different prices in different categories then there are 3 options;

1. Setup the product twice with a different SKU and manage the
   categories and prices accordingly.
2. Use group prices so that only
   particular customers can see one price, other customers will see the
   other price.
3. Use store views to override the price per each store
   view.

You need to re-assess exactly what you are trying to achieve and tailor your setup around one of these 3 possible solutions. I wouldn't implement a whole pricing by category system, it will get very complicated, very quickly and Magento provides functionality to achieve this using the above methods.